# File Not Found error even though the two filenames are exactly the same?

Tags: go

I'm writing a crawler in Go that crawls the trendmicro site for security reports (in pdf form), then uses wget when it gets a hit on a pdf to download the pdf. Afterwards, I use a library I found from github (https://github.com/sajari/docconv) to translate the pdf into text, then print that text to the terminal. For some reason, the code works just fine for the first two pdfs, but once it hits the third, it says that the pdf was not found, even though it downloads just the same as the others and is in the same directory. The program trace is below:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2268867 (2.2M) [application/pdf]
Saving to: ‘rpt-2016-annual-security-roundup-a-record-year-for-enterprise-threats.pdf’

rpt-2016-annual-sec 100%[===================>]   2.16M  1.02MB/s    in 2.1s    

2019-02-20 15:25:07 (1.02 MB/s) - ‘rpt-2016-annual-security-roundup-a-record-year-for-enterprise-threats.pdf’ saved [2268867/2268867]

2019/02/20 15:25:07 open rpt-2016-annual-security-roundup-a-record-year-for-enterprise-threats.pdf : no such file or directory
exit status 1
```

I diff'd the two strings to see if they're different but they're not. And again, the first two download just fine. Here's the affected part of the code:

```
pdfName := strings.Replace(link, "https://documents.trendmicro.com/assets/rpt/", "", -1)
fmt.Printf("PDF name: %s\n", pdfName)
existingPdf := 0;
if len(pdfs) > 0 {
    for i := 0; i < len(pdfs); i++ {
        if pdfs[i] == pdfName {
            existingPdf = 1;
        }
    }
}
if existingPdf == 0 {
    pdfs = append(pdfs, pdfName)
    command := "wget " + link
    cmd := exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", command, ">",  "/dev/null", "2>&1")
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    cmd.Run()
    res, err := docconv.ConvertPath(pdfName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

If you'd like the full code and/or would like to run it, I've put it in pastebin (https://pastebin.com/5JkJDamV)

Comment: You can't pass `">",  "/dev/null", "2>&1"` as arguments to bash, they need to be in `command` if you want bash to interpret them as part of `command`

Comment: I removed the redirection from my command, but it unfortunately did not stop the FNF error

Comment: No, that was just a basic error I saw. Also, why are you shelling out to `wget` in the first place, instead of just downloading the file directly? I would make sure everything is in the same working directory, and verify the file exists from the commandline too.

Comment: I have done those things, the file exists and is named the same as what the command is looking for. What would you mean by downloading the file directly? That's what wget is for, a file download through the shell. Unless there is an included go tool tool that is easier to use I don't know why wget would be bad to use. Also I've edited my question to include a pastebin with the code

Comment: `wget` isn't bad, it's just adding more variables to your problem. The go http package works perfectly fine. Did you verify that there's no hidden whitespace in the name that the shell would be stripping out for you?

Comment: I didn't know of the package but I'll look into it - I'm a bit new to go. Anyway, I have looked at the files and none of them have whitespace, all the words in the file are delimited by a hyphen. I also thought of that before I posted but unfortunately that's also not the issue

Comment: whitespace would most likely be at the end, not where the hyphens are. Just use `fmt.Printf("PDF name: %q\n", pdfName)` rather than guessing at what characters may or may not be there.

Comment: NO WAY - there is an extra space at the end of the filename on the last one! Great job @JimB. Post your answer and I'll accept